# Biconnected graph

Tags: graph-theory

**Let $P$ be a piece of a bi-connected graph with respect to a cycle $C$.**

- Show that if $P$ has at least one vertex, the number of edges of $P$ is
  greater than or equal to the number of attachments of $P$.
- Equally show that the graph obtained by adding $P$ to $C$ is
  bi-connected.

Comment: This is a bonus assignment and i could not figure it out. Thus i need help.

Comment: I understand what a biconnected graph is, but I'm confused about the "with respect to a cycle" part. Can you explain what kind of graph is biconnected w.r.t a cycle?

Comment: My understanding of w.r.t a cycle is if you start form one vertex and traverse through the graph and comes back to the same vertex.

Comment: If you traverse through every connected graph you can come back to the original vertex.

Comment: Then am not sure what it means but the question is correct. I saw the same question on one website as well.

Comment: Similar question on this website, number 5       http://www.ics.uci.edu/~goodrich/teach/ics163/hw/hw6.html